# How to copy one pointer content located inside an array of structs to another pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following lists, one of packs made with connected structs, one of trucks, made with a static array.

```
typedef struct
{
    int id_pack;
    int weight_kg;
    int value;
    int priority;           //low 0, high 1
    struct pack* next;
} pack;

typedef struct pack head;  //declaring a struct head of type pack which is the head of a list of packs

typedef struct
{
    int id_truck;
    head* p_head;            //pointer to the list of packs of each truck
} truck;

int main()
{
    truck dogana[N];        //list of trucks made with a static array
}
```

Now, I want to make a function that checks whether the priority of at least one pack of the list of packs of the first truck is high priority (1).
In order to do so I thought of making a temporary pointer to avoid losing the reference to the head of the list of packs (I need it for other things I must do inside the function); this is my function.

```
void uscita_dogana (truck dogana[])
{
    head* temp;
    temp = dogana[0].p_head; // I use temp to avoid losing the head 

    while (temp != NULL)   //cicle to run trough the packs
    {
        if (temp->priority == 1) //check the priority of the pack
        {
           //INSTRUCTIONS
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler gives me an error at 
    temp->priority == 1
which says "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'head {aka struct pack};

I tried many different things to solve this, but didn't manage to. 
I asked for help and searched around the site but couldn't find the right solution, I hope someone can help me!

I'm sorry for the general confusion, english is not my first language and I've just started coding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since `head` isn't a different struct, giving it a `typedef` creates some confusion. It looks like a different type, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a type `pack` as an alias for an anonymous struct (note that you do not have an identifier after keyword `struct` in `typedef struct { ... } pack`.

When you later define

```
typedef struct pack head;
```

then you are referring to `struct pack`, which has not been defined yet. The compiler will note this as an incomplete type, such that `head` will be an incomplete type, too. That's why `temp->priority` with `temp`being of type `head` is not known.

Write

```
typedef pack head;
```

and it should work.